# Data getting stored using AsyncStorage only after 2-3 submit button clicks in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am calling a function on press of a button, to store my data in local storage using `AsyncStorage`.

Below is my code to store data using `AsyncStorage`

```
const [saveData, setSaveData] = useState([]);

const _submit = async (text, photo) => {
  let newItem;
  
  newItem = {
    description: text,
    imageURL: photo,
  };
  setSaveData(prevList => {
    prevList = prevList || [];
    if (prevList.length < 0) {
      return newItem;
    } else {
      return [...prevList, newItem];
    }
  });
  setLocalItem();
};

const setLocalItem = async () => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem('test2', JSON.stringify(saveData))
    .then(json => console.log('success!'))
    .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
};

const getLocalItem = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('test2');
    const list = JSON.parse(jsonValue);

    console.log('list: ', list);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error: ', e);
  }
};

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    _submit (text, photo);
  }}>
  <Text>save</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    getLocalItem();
  }}>
  <Text>get item</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

My data is getting stored but only after I click `save` button multiple times. But in console I am getting `success` even when I click `save` button only once. But when I click on `get item` button, I am getting `null` in console if `save` is clicked only once.

I am not not sure why I have to click `save` multiple times to store my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're updating the state incorrectly. And the new state will be available in the next render, so `setLocalItem` should be called after the state gets updated.

```
const [saveData, setSaveData] = useState([]);

// this effect updates the storage whenever `saveData` changes
useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('test2', JSON.stringify(saveData))
    .then(json => console.log('success!'))
    .catch(error => console.log('error!'));
}, [saveData])

const _submit = (text, photo) => {
  const newItem = {
    description: text,
    imageURL: photo,
  };

  // no conditions are required here as the initial state is an array
  setSaveData(prevList => [...prevList, newItem]);
};


const getLocalItem = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('test2');
    const list = JSON.parse(jsonValue);

    console.log('list: ', list);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error: ', e);
  }
};
```